# Galois group of $\mathbb{C}(x(1-y),y(1-x)) \subset \mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

> I would like to compute the Galois group $ G $ of the extension $\mathbb{C}(x(1-y),y(1-x)) \subset \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

So far I have no idea how to determine $ G $ though I think it should be the Klein group $ C_{2} \times C_{2} $. What I know is that $ x-y \in L $ as it is simply the difference $ x(1-y)-y(1-x) $.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I, too, was first thinking that it would be Klein four. But, the fact that $y-x$ is in the smaller field makes it more believable that the extension is quadratic. Finding the non-trivial automorphism was then not too difficult. I have little bit of experience with single variable function fields, and that helped here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $K=\Bbb{C}(x(1-y),y(1-x))$, $L=\Bbb{C}(x,y)$.

Consider the endomorphism $\tau$ of $\Bbb{C}$-algebras of $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ defined by
$$
\tau:x\mapsto 1-y,\quad y\mapsto 1-x.
$$
We easily see that $\tau$ is its own inverse, and maps both $x(1-y)$ and $y(1-x)$ to themselves. Therefore $\tau$ induces a $K$-automorphism of $L$. Let's look at the polynomial
$$
p(T):=(T-x)(T-\tau(x))=T^2-(x+\tau(x))T+x\tau(x)=T^2-(x-y+1)T+x(1-y).
$$
Your crucial observation $x(1-y)-y(1-x)=x-y\in K$ (from an earlier version of the question) implies that $p(T)\in K[T]$. But $p(x)=0$, so we see that $[K(x):K]\le 2$. This settles pretty much everything:

- Because $y-x\in K$, we have $y\in K(x)$, so $L=K(x)$ and $[L:K]\le2$.
- Because $\tau$ is non-trivial, its fixed field is a proper subfield. As $K$ is containted in the fixed field, we conclude that $[L:K]\ge2$, and $p(T)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$.
- Therefore $[L:K]=2$, and the Galois group is generated by $\sigma$.

Comment: Great answer(+1)! Thank you. I was quite convinced it should be $ C_{2} \times C_{2} $ but you proved me wrong.

Comment: Looking at the quadratic polynomial $p(T)$ we may want to calculate its discriminant:
$$D=(x-y+1)^2-4x(1-y)=(x+y-1)^2.$$ So adjoining $\sqrt{D}=x+y-1$ also works. It may actually be "more symmetric" to check that $(x+y-1)^2$ is in the smaller field.